# Why does returning Set from a Spring Data JPA Repository works although it shouldn't?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple `JpaRepository` like that:

```java
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Integer> {
    
    Set<Group> findAllByStudentsStudentId(Long studentId);
    
}
```

According to this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-return-map-instead-of-list) as well as to these [Supported Query Return Types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/query-return-types-reference.html#appendix.query.return.types), returning a `Set` shouldn't function out of the box. Therefore I assume, that `Spring Data JPA` somehow converts the return type into a set anyway.

My questions are:

1. Why is this possible although nowhere mentioned (or did I missunderstand something)?
2. If Spring converts the return type, does Spring convert afterwards, meaning first a `List` (or `Iterable`) is build and then as a followup operation the List gets turned into a Set, or is the Set in place right from the start while the result rows get merged into their entities?

Many thanks for any clarification

Comment: The Spring link you posted specifically *does* list Set as a supported return type. The Baeldung article is probably just old and in need of updating or wrong.

Comment: Stupid me, I really just have missed the `Vavr` collection types - never heard about before. Thanks for pointing this out. So one question remains: when does Spring convert the returning type, since when it's done additionally I can do it by myself later on as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses a `ConversionService` to convert types, so I'd imagine that the JPA stuff uses that.

Spring picks up that `ConversionService` and uses it whenever a type conversion needs to be performed by the framework.

I think (code is not tested) that you can `@Autowire` it if you want to examine the object that Spring sets up in your context.

```
@Configuration class ConvServiceAccess {
   public String conversionServiceDumper(ConversionService svc){
       // This will let you dump/debug the service.
       System.out.println("Conversion service: " + svc);
       return "Noop";
   }
}
```

Docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/validation/convert.html

Javadocs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/package-summary.html